# Can I enable/diable groups of breakpoints in C++ Builder?

Tags: c++builder

One specific instance, I want to set a BP on every switch(msg) handled in WndProc() - but not until my app has initialized and is 'stable'. Of course, it receives a lot of windows messages when it starts up.

I can't see a way to toggle a group of breakpoints, or to save them for later, use other BPs then restore the first set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed set a breakpoint (which doesn't even have to break) to enable/disable a group of breakpoints. (This goes back to BCB6 at least)
This EDN article shows the relevant dialog boxes:
http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/31263
It also describes how to use groups.